# cl.exe not found in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, cuda, visual-studio-2017, nvcc

I installed Visual Studio for Nvidia CUDA Programming, though upon running

```
nvcc -o 1 hello.cu
```

I get an error saying

```
nvcc fatal   : Cannot find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH
```

I searched in This PC/Windows(C:)/Program Files(x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC
but there is no bin folder here, neither is cl.exe executable

Comment: Which feature? may you please elaborate?

Comment: No I don't think its duplicate of that answer, I went through it, couldn't find the solution

Comment: Which _option_ ?  I tried a lot of stuff, nothing worked